# QWERTY keyboard string length

Tags: code-golf, keyboard

QWERTY keyboard distance (QKD) is, in short, the distance between two letters/numbers/punctuation keys on a standard QWERTY keyboard (if you don't have one around, you can check this [Wikipedia picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Qwerty.svg)). Note that only characters without modifiers be considered for this challenge  (so <kbd>;</kbd> is valid, but <kbd>)</kbd> is not).

**Some examples:**

```
>> QKD("a","s")
 1
>> QKD("e","f")
 2
>> QKD("g",".")
 5
```

In this code-golf challenge you will have to compute the QWERTY string length (QSL), which is the sum of the QWERTY keyboard distances between every two consecutive characters of a given string. E.g. `QSL("abcd") = QKD("a", "b") + QKD("b", "c") + QKD("c", "d")`

**Examples:**

```
>> QSL("code-golf")
 37 // QKD(c,o) + QKD(o,d) + QKD(d,e) + .. = 6  +  6 + 1 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 1 + 5 = 37
>> QSL("puzzles")
 25 // 3 + 6 + 0 + 8 + 7 + 1
>> QSL("stackexchange")
 43 // 3 + 4 + 3 + 5 + 6 + 2 + 1 + 3 + 5 + 6 + 2 + 3
```

**Some notes:**

- You have to support at least <kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd>.
- When you aren't sure about the distance between two characters, refer to the [Wikipedia picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Qwerty.svg).
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed, as usual (you knew that, didn't you?).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), thus shortest code wins.

Comment: @TimmyD Hm... looks similar, but the distance metric is different `:)`

Comment: This may not be exactly the same, but it is *very* similar to the duplicate. This question doesn't really add much that the other one doesn't have.

Comment: Ok, no problem...

Comment: You may not have been aware of this, but on Meta there is a [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where you can post challenges that you'd like to post on the main site and get feedback, including any [almost]-duplicates or requests for clarification, perceived problems pointed out, that sort of thing. It really helps to sandbox your challenges first.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman I'm aware of it.... Just didn't think about it before posting :D